# Sono fatti così. Non c'è da prendersela

Tags: idioms

I'm a bit puzzled by this construction. My attempt is:

"They're like this. It's not worth getting angry about"

I understand 'prendersela', but not the 'c'è da' part.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*C'è da* is another way to say *bisogna*, so *non c'è da prendersela* means "(there's) no need to get angry", "you should not get angry". Similar constructs are *non c'è da stupirsi, non c'è da preoccuparsi, c'è da fare.*

You might hear *Sei da amare* (and similar), i.e. "You're a treasure", or something like *Quei tizi sono da evitare*, i.e. "You better avoid those guys". But do note it's different: the second person of *c'è da* would be *ci sei da*, and **this**, as well as *ci siete da, ci siamo da*, is almost always (*) meaningless; however, *Ci sono ancora i bagni da pulire*, *Ci sono i condizionatori da aggiustare* do make sense and are actually what you should say instead of *C'è ancora da pulire i bagni, C'è da aggiustare i condizionatori*. In other words, if the verb is transitive, *c'è da* becomes *ci sono* object *da* if the object is plural.

(*) *Ah dimenticavo, ci siete voi/ci sei tu da sistemare!* is a very very rare exception.

Comment: So this construction is used like bisogna, i.e. only in the third person impersonal? Would 'sei da fare' mean anything? Also, can it be used in the positive or only with 'non'?

Comment: @Scoiattolo: See if my edit is satisfying. The examples *non c'è da stupirsi, c'è da fare* show that it can be used both positively and negatively.